# Get key of a hashmap withou know it's name

Tags: javascript, hashmap

Having one only key/value into an object, how to get them without know the key name? (If it's possible)

```
var m = {x:5}; // we don't know x is the key
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [read name of unknown properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807059/read-name-of-unknown-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` for things like this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty

```
var m = {x:5};

function keys(obj)
{
    var keys = [];

    for(var key in obj)
    {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {    
        {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }

    return keys;
}

console.log(m);
```

So using this knowledge, you can write a function that basically checks whether a given key exists in an object:

```
function hasKey(obj, key) {
   return obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `for…in` loop, if the browser support ES5 (or has a shim for ES5):

```
var key = Object.keys(m)[0];
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys