# How to use ng-repeat of an array of objects if keys are not known

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects that I want to use to generate the content and properties of a table cell. The keys of the objects in the array may be different from time to time, so I want to use a generic way to get the keys from each object in the array, ie: `ng-repeat="(key, value) in health"`. I don't know how to use ng-repeat in order to do this since I feel like I need to do a chain of ng-repeat, but the way I want to generate the table cell doesn't seem to allow me to do this.

This is the JSON (my problem is for the health key):

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "host": "",
    "health": [{
        "netwatch": "GOOD"
        }, {
        "dns": "UNKNOWN"
     }]
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<td ng-repeat="health in server.health" ng-class="[main.getHealthBgClass(// need value of object here), main.getHealthTextClass(// need value of object here), 'healthcell']"> {{//I want the key of the object here}} </td>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you mean that in some cases you might need to read `server.otherkey` instead of `server.health`?

Comment: What I am saying is that I am trying to iterate through the objects in the server.health array. And I need some way to retrieve the key/value pairs or each object in the server.health array. But all of this must be done in the <td> tag because the content of the <td> tag is the key, and there are classes that are added to the <td> tag that are based on the value of that key.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the value of the health key to `getHealthBgClass` and `getHealthTextClass` you might try do do something like they do here: [read name of unknown properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807059/read-name-of-unknown-properties)

Comment: But how do I get the value in the first place? I'm asking about how to use ng-repeat.

Comment: main.getHealthBgClass(health) ?

Comment: Yes, but then how do I display the key as text? I can't do {{key}} like I could by using a normal version of ng-repeat="(key,value) in server.health"

Comment: Ah. I see. The key of the object! You would need a new function that takes a health object and return the key?

Comment: So in your controller you would create a function that takes an health object and returns the key as text.  $scope.getKeyText = function(health) {...}